# R: How can I expand a value in a row based on the other row's value in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, assign

For example, I now have a dataframe

```
data = cbind(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
             value = c('a', '','b', '', 'a', ''))
```

I want to expand things in the *value* column based on the column *id*.
Something like this, where when id is 1, value will all be 'a':

```
data = cbind(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
             value = c('a', 'a','b','b','a','a'))
```

Thank you!

Comment: as i am not sure if the answer, for which the question was closed, is exactly what you are looking for i offer this option: `data = cbind.data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
value = c('a', '','b', '', 'a', ''))`

`dat<-ifelse(data$id==1, data$value<-"a", "b")` you can nest the ifelse() should you want to change it depending on your id response like so: `dat<-ifelse(data$id==1, data$value<-"a", ifelse(data$id==2, "b", "a"))`

Comment: 1. `data = data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), value = c('a', '','b', '', 'a', ''))`. 2. `data[data == ''] <- NA`. 3. `data %>%group_by(id) %>%  fill(value)` The solution needs `dplyr` and `tidyr`.